# Easy way to use vim for an svn conflict?

Tags: svn, vim

I just ran into a conflict while working in SVN, and I find myself missing a bit of functionality from Mercurial.  In Mercurial, I have `vim -d` set up as my diff tool.  I'm wondering if there is a way to get SVN to work in a similar way?  Something along the lines of:

```
$ svn resolve whatever.py
```

Which would bring up vim (in diff mode), allow me to fix the file, and then do an `svn resolved` to clean up.  I work exclusively in CLI (mostly over SSH), so graphical diff tools need not apply.

Does such a thing exist?

**Update:**
It is probably worth including where in the process I am.  I've edited a file (`whatever.py`), saved it, and done an `svn update` where someone else has also changed the file.  So my `svn stat` looks like so:

```
?      whatever.py.mine
?      whatever.py.r7822
?      whatever.py.r7908
C      whatever.py
```

Comment: Have you looked at svndiff?
PS
Just googled and found this for vim: http://zevv.nl/play/code/vimscripts/

Comment: That appears to be comparing `HEAD` to current.  Not fixing up a conflict.  I'll probably download it, but it doesn't solve this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678860/svn-using-vim-to-merge-conflicts/19678861#19678861

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever I have a conflict from a `svn update`, I'm asked for a half dozen options, one of which is to edit the file in question.  Perhaps you need a newer version of Subversion.  I'm running 1.6.9.

Comment: This is a pretty old version of subversion, but the question still applies if I decide to postpone resolving this issue.

Comment: So... You're right.  The only thing that is missing is the command to actually do the merge.  It's `svn merge`.  Once I got the updated version, it worked.  Toss that in there so I can mark it right.  =-]

Answer (score 4):

set vim as diff tool for Tortoise, for win32 (work for me):

1) Tortoise SVN->Settings->external Programms->diff tool

> set External C:\programs\gVim\vim73\gvim.exe -d
>
> set External C:\programs\gVim\vim73\gvim.exe -d

2) unified diff Viewer

> C:\programs\gVim\vim73\gvim.exe

3)Merge Tool

> "C:\programs\gVim\vim73\gvim.exe" -f -d -c "wincmd J" -c "resize 22" %merged %theirs %mine %base

Comment: I've gone with this for the merge: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\gvim.exe" -d --cmd "set lines=999 columns=999" -c "wincmd J" %merged %theirs %base %mine`

Answer (score 1):

In more recent versions of the subversion CLI client, you can set an environment variable `SVN_MERGE=vim -d` and then select `l` to launch external tool when a conflict menu comes up during an svn update.

I'm not 100% sure if the parameter order passed by svn matches the one required by vim -d so you might have to write a wrapper script instead of directly calling vim.

The svn manual has full details, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the environment variables `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` to vim

Comment: That works for commits and the like, but it doesn't change the diff.  I'm already using vim as my `EDITOR`.