# svn: using vim to merge conflicts

Tags: svn, vim

I am trying see how merging in svn can be made easy.

This [page](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html) mentions that external tools can be used for merging.
Can vim be used as the external merge tool?

Some additional requirements:

1. Files should be split horizontally/vertically to give a better view.
2. Window titles should be set appropriately.

e.g: as in 
[image]

Comment: @romainl: Google brought me on this page, so I actually thanks the guy.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Step 1:

Save the following script, e.g: merger.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
#


BASE=${1}
THEIRS=${2}
MINE=${3}
MERGED=${4}
WCPATH=${5}

vimdiff $MINE $THEIRS -c ":botright split $MERGED" -c ":diffthis" -c "setl statusline=MERGED | wincmd W | setl statusline=THEIRS | wincmd W | setl statusline=MINE"
```

Step 2:

Edit  `.subversion/config` and add following line:

```
merge-tool-cmd = /path/to/merger.sh
```

Step 3:

When you get following options during svn merge command, select option '`l`'.
This is to launch external tool to resolve conflicts.

```
Conflict discovered in 'main.h'.
Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit,
        (mc) mine-conflict, (tc) theirs-conflict,
        (s) show all options: l
```

Step 4:
Now vim will be opened in diff mode with 3 files - mine, theirs and merged.
Make the required changes in the merged file, and do save and exit (`:wqa`).

Step 5:

Now below options will appear again, select '`r`' (to accept the merged version) now.

```
Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit,
            (mc) mine-conflict, (tc) theirs-conflict,
            (s) show all options: r
```

Comment: If this change is not needed on a permanent basis, it can also be done by setting the environment variable SVN_MERGE=/path/to/merger.sh

Comment: How might I use this script to resolve a messy workspace with conflicts from an "svn update"? I have a bunch of .r*, .mine files, but not sure how to get my workspace back in a clean state again.

Comment: The additions on this answer helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312089/how-to-get-external-merge-tools-to-work-with-svn-on-linux

Comment: If you meet the error: `The external merge tool exited with exit code 255` after step 3, then `chmod +x merger.sh`